# New file creation using Python is containing special character

Tags: python

```
>>> with open('/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/ud_final_id.txt', 'r') as ciid:
...   for udcid in ciid:
...     open(f"/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/UDID/{udcid}","w")
... 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/UDID/4f552eb733e2a8aaa2f1950bef6efac7\n' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/UDID/4a81a02538598bd4b90f57ed75457e5b\n' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/UDID/4af35b87154d5d4aab6b8637dcd6b7be\n' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/UDID/470031350886ba1f91d6e23d09cf4186\n' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/amitsh/PYTHON/AZURE/logs/UDID/4826f82391df0920bc0891cebfb52462\n' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

```
[root@XXXX UDID]# ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 4f552eb733e2a8aaa2f1950bef6efac7?
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 4a81a02538598bd4b90f57ed75457e5b?
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 4af35b87154d5d4aab6b8637dcd6b7be?
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 4826f82391df0920bc0891cebfb52462?
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 470031350886ba1f91d6e23d09cf4186?
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 489a46b15e1edb488544ab383887e2d2?
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 13 19:12 47b25e62090aff7280c1973c60764ef1?
```

The new files are having question mark "?" due to which the program is not running.
Need your support in managing this issue.

I need these files to put data which is gathered from API's.

Comment: Please add more details, such as a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Look closely at the output. `udcid` still contains a newline character.

Comment: As @Botje said; so, replace `{udcid}` with `{udcid.strip()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop over a file's lines, you'll also get the trailing newline, which `ls` represents as a `?`.

After `for udcid in ciid:`, add `udcid = udcid.strip()` to strip all surrounding whitespace from the line you've read.